# What are the differences between ( , ), [ , ] and $\langle$ ,$\rangle$ $?$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

> What are the differences between ( , ), [ , ] and $\langle$ ,$\rangle$ $?$

Pardon me for asking stupid questions like this but I'm pretty confused by all these symbols :(

Comment: In what context???

Comment: There is no general rule, even in linear algbera alone, you need to read you course (or your exercise) to know... However usually $(,)$ will mean a bilinear form, $[,]$ will usually denote the Lie product for matrices $[A,B]=AB-BA$ and $<,>$ will usually denote a scalar product... Once again it strongly depends on notational conventions...

Comment: @barakmanos In the case of a n-dimensional vector, what are the differences between (a1, ..., an), [a1, ..., an] and <a1, ..., an>?

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no straight forward difference between them because many times they can be used interchangibly without loss of meaning depending on what nomenaclure one is using. There are however "guidelines" in the losest sense possible.

Answer (score 2):

Possible meanings of $(x,y)$ include:

- The ordered pair with components $x$ and $y$ (e.g., the 2D point with coordinates $x$ and $y$)
- The open interval of all real numbers strictly between $x$ and $y$
- The scalar product of vectors $x$ and $y$

Possible meanings of $[x,y]$ include:

- The closed interval of all real numbers between $x$ and $y$ (inclusive)
- The Lie bracket of vectors $x$ and $y$

Possible meanings of $\langle x,y\rangle$ include:

- The ordered pair with components $x$ and $y$
- The scalar product of vectors $x$ and $y$
- The (sub-)group generated by $x$ and $y$

Actually, I suppose that any option listed under one notation is used by at least some authors also by the other notations even if not listed above. I explicitly do not attempt to explain all other possible syntactical possibilities for yet other (widespread conventional) meanings, such as $(x)$, $[x]$, $\langle x\rangle$, $f(x)$, $f[x]$, $A[x]$, $F(x)$, $x\choose y$,  $\left({x\over y}\right)$, $\left[{x\atop y}\right]$, $\left\langle{x\atop y}\right\rangle$, $\left[{x\atop y}\right]$ and whatnot.

Comment: Pardon my intrusion, but what does $f[x]$ mean?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD application of $f$, in some contexts.  Sometimes it's used when $x$ is a discrete variable.  Sometimes it's used when the codomain of $f$ is a set of functions, so that $f[x]$ is a function that may be written as $f[x](y)$.